# .htaccess mod rewrite 500 error

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Why would I all of a sudden start getting a 500 error from my .htaccess file. I havent changed anything for 3 years, now when i access the site I get a 500 error. Here is my .htaccess file. I have removed everything from my root directory and created a brand new blank index.php file and I get still get this error.

```
 Options +FollowSymLinks
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /

 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.thisismyurl\.com [NC]
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.thisismyurl.com/$1 [R=301,L]

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php [L]
```

Comment: Can you check your Apache error.log?

Comment: Can you paste the error from your apache error log?

Comment: The apache error log defaults to `/var/log/apache2/error.log` under linux. Get the last few errors from that and edit your post to add them here.

Comment: @Jonathan, that's not for all linux distros. For some, like Cent OS/Red Hat/Fedora, it defaults to `/var/log/httpd`. Debian based distros default to `/var/log/apache2`. Not sure about the other distros, but it should be in one of the 2 aforementioned folders.

Comment: Was Apache upgraded ? frome 2.2 to 2.4 there is a bunch of config changes...